# Copy subdirectory from various folders to one folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

I'm struggling with this situation, any help will be welcome.

I have this system of folders:

```
FatherFolder1
             Subfolder1
                       folder1
                       folder2
                       folder3
                       folder4
             Subfolder2
                       folder1
                       folder2
                       folder3
                       folder4
             Subfolder3
                       folder1
                       folder2
                       folder3
                       folder4
```

I would need copy every "folder4" from every "Subfolder" to one specific folder

There is any way to do this with a .bat ?

Thanks.

EDIT: I thought of something like "copy 'fatherfolder1\*\folder4' 'c:\specificDir'" But it says "Incorrect sintax" :(

Comment: Yes. There is. The command is called Copy

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to build a .bat to search for "folder4" on every "Subfolder" if you understand me ...

Comment: Is `folder4` one particular name, or does the fourth folder change?

Comment: sorry for the delay, its been a very busy month for me, but no, "folder4" is always the same name, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`/D` will iterate over the directories that match the specified pattern. By itself, it will not recurse (/R).

```
FOR /D %%d IN (FatherFolder1\*.*) DO (
    COPY %%d\folder4\*.* %TARGET_FOLDER%
)
```